# Telerik GridViewPinButton visibility in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

I've encountered a strange issue regarding the `GridViewPinButton` visibility in `RadGridView`.

My only wish is to disable this functionality- to set the `GridViewPinButton` visibility to collapse in every row in `RadGridView`.

Now, I have one place where it works great and another one where I can see this button while I'm hovering the rows.

In both places I haven't written any code concerning the `GridViewPinButton` , and in both cases the visibility of the button is set to collapsed by default.

The only difference I can see is in snoop :
When it works well, `GridViewPinButton` does not have any child elements:

[image]
 while it has them in the second case (where it does not work well):
[image]

When I click the button, I get the error:

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure `Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Strings.resources` was correctly embedded or linked into assembly `Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView` at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Stack trace is attached:

```
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.GetBlockAndPosition(Object item, Boolean deletedFromItems, GeneratorPosition& position, ItemBlock& block, Int32& offsetFromBlockStart, Int32& correctIndex)
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.OnItemReplaced(Object oldItem, Object newItem, Int32 index)
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList.DeliverEvent(Listener& listener, Object sender, EventArgs args, Type managerType)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(Object sender, EventArgs args, ListenerList list)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection.OnPinnedItemsCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection.AddToPinnedItems(Object item)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(CommandBindingCollection commandBindings, Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TransferEvent(IInputElement newSource, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadButton.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
```

on your RadGridView